# Messages are reading but not processed

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Application is reading the message from MQ but showing null. Queue is empty after starting the application. When I stop the application it is going back to the queue and showing as an uncommitted message

```
  protected final XaTransactedJmsMessageReceiver.ThreadContextLocal context = new XaTransactedJmsMessageReceiver.ThreadContextLocal();

  JmsThreadContext ctx = context.getContext();

  message = ctx.consumer.receive(timeout);
  logger.debug("Message : " + message); // showing as a null here
```

Update :

When I open message on MQ Explorer,  Message data bytes shows like below

```
 00000   3C 00 3F 00 78 00 6D 00--6C 00 20 00 76 00 65 00  |����������������|
 00010   72 00 73 00 69 00 6F 00--6E 00 3D 00 22 00 31 00  |����������������|
```

Messages are reading if message like this, then is it reading

```
00000   3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65--72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31  |<?xml version="1|
00010   2E 30 22 20 65 6E 63 6F--64 69 6E 67 3D 22 75 74  |.0" encoding="ut|
```

This looks like MQ related issue, Can some help how the message formatting get changed?

Added Image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you viewed the message with another tool, is it actually NULL? What version of IBM MQ are your jar files from?

Comment: It looks like not a valid message(Not sure). When I open the message in MQ explorer, I can see like below. 00000   3C 00 3F 00 78 00 6D 00--6C 00 20 00 76 00 65 00  |����������������|

Comment: What does the message format and ccsid of the message show up as in the MQMD?  It appears those that you say you can not read are CCSID 1200 if I had to guess, so if the format is not MQSTR or the CCSID is wrong them you may experience problems.

Comment: @JoshMc, I dont know what is CCSID. Can you please let me know where to check it? The format is MQSTR.

Comment: In the screenshot you added it is the field "Coded character set indentifier".  It appears the readable message is CCSID 1208, what is it for the unreadable message?

Comment: Yes, CCID is 1200, Can you please let me know how to set up it to 1208?

Comment: Why can't we see messages with CCSID with 1200. these messages are utf16 right?

Comment: what version of MQ? Data conversion was changed in v9 particularly around UTF-16 and the CCSID 1200.

Comment: MQ v9, application cant read 1200 messages?

Comment: What is the format of the 1200 message? Can you add a screen shot from a unreadable message?

Comment: Added. Please check it above

Comment: Can you provide the exact version 9 that the jar files are from?  ex: 9.0.0.6 or 9.0.2 or 9.1.0.1 or 9.1.2?

Comment: allclient jar version 9.0.0.2  and MQ version :     9.0.4.0

Comment: Do you mean the queue manager is 9.0.4?

Comment: Could be. I am getting following:

$dspmqver 
Name: IBM MQ 
Version: 9.0.4.0

Comment: Did this work before in a previous version?  If so what version was that.

Comment: Yes, It works before on 7.5.0.4

Comment: Can you try setting this java system property and see if it changes the behavior to what you saw at 7.5.0.4?  `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterAction=REPLACE`.  Prior to v8.0 this is how it would have behaved, after v8.0 it defaults to `REPORT`.

Comment: The last suggestion would apply if you were hitting a situation where a character could not be converted, 
but after further review can you try this and see if it makes a difference?  `logger.debug("Message : " + message.getText());`